# Matlab - ActiveX Move Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

Which is the command to move an excel sheet after another from one book to other?. Commented lines failed.

```
X = actxserver('Excel.Application'); 
XW0 = X.Workbooks.Open('t0.xlsx'); 
XW2 = X.Workbooks.Open('t2.xlsx'); 
XW2.Worksheets.Item(1).Name = 't2';
% XW2.Worksheets.Item(1).Move('after',XW0.Sheets(1));
XW0.Save
XW0.Close(false)
XW2.Save
XW2.Close(false)
X.Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get Sheet `t2` to move from `t2.xlsx` to after Sheet 1 in `t0.xlsx` by replacing your commented-out line with this:

```
XW2.Worksheets.Item(1).Move([], XW0.WorkSheets.Item(1));
```

Note the empty matrix for the first argument, which is where the *Before* option goes (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834742.aspx)).